# How to type return value as "throw"

Tags: flowtype

Sometimes my function will throw. I want to add this to the return type. In TypeScript we set the return type to `never`. Is there an equivalent strategy in Flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow have `empty` type. Take a look at example of [Typing Redux reducers](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/redux/#toc-typing-redux-reducers), also can work as returned type for function.

```
/* @flow */

function foo():empty {
    throw new Error();
}

function baz():empty {
    return 42;
}

    return 42;
           ^ Cannot return `42` because number [1] is incompatible with empty [2].
References:
8:  return 42;
           ^ [1]
7: function baz():empty {
                  ^ [2]
```

Comment: Thank you @Buggy! Excuse delay in accepting solution, I didn't see this.